# Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied

Tags: php, windows, apache

I am trying to make a directory when a new account is created.
 
The directory should be in my images folder and is used to better separate uploaded images.

```
//get the ID of the new account that was just created/inserted
$accountID = mysqli_insert_id($dbc);

//create a new directory path for that account
$directoryPath =  "../images/" . $accountID;

// check if the directory exists
if (!is_dir($directoryPath)) {
    //create the directory
    mkdir($directoryPath, 0777);         //breaking here
}
```

I had no problem getting this to work a few days ago, however when testing it today I am having problems.

I have included `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` in my page to see what error I am being thrown and it is a permission error.

`Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied`

The images folder has full read/write permissions for all users and groups as well as any parent folders so I don't understand how that would be an issue, that and it had worked several times before.

I am working on windows if that matters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid spending too much time on permissions problems between the CLI user and the Apache user, an easy configuration is to use same user for both processes.

Get your user id and group by doing

```
$ id
uid=1000(my_user), gid=1000(my_group), ...
```

And then:

```
$ sudo service apache2 stop
$ sudo vi /etc/apache2/envvars
export APACHE_RUN_USER=my_user
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=my_group
$ sudo chown -R my_user /var/lock/apache2
```

it's better and safer than to change you whole directory permission to 777

Comment: But due to change in uid gid, it seems codeigniter cannot write its sessions in /var/lib/php/sessions/ci_sessionxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this -

```
mkdir("../images/".$accountID, 0777, 'R');
```

Recursive folder creation may causing the problem.
Also get more information from - [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

Also check for folder permission.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure that the parent directory allows you to create folder, and not the folder it self that is being created with **0777** rights...
Also, check with which user the **Apache** server is launched 
Check if directory is already exist before using `mkdir()`

```
if (!is_dir ($directoryPath) ) {
    mkdir($directoryPath, 0777);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I have this already and i am still getting the this problem, should have been in my answer sorry, I will edit it now. However how would I go about checking which user the apache server is launched?

Comment: how do you lanch your Apache Server ? service or command line ?

Comment: if your on debian/ubuntu : service apache2 start or /etc/init.d/apache2 start

Answer (score 0):

> I am working on windows if that matters.

It does.

Try changing this

```
if (!is_dir($directoryPath)) {
    //create the directory
    mkdir($directoryPath, 0777);         //breaking here
}
```

To this

```
if (!is_dir($directoryPath)) {
    //create the directory
    mkdir($directoryPath);         //breaking here
}
```

You are on a **Windows** box so it will ignore the chmod mode. Also try using the full paths and not relative.

> The mode is 0777 by default, which means the widest possible access.
>   For more information on modes, read the details on the chmod() page.
>
> **Note:mode is ignored on Windows**.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: I tried taking out `0777` and I am still being thrown the same permission issue. What would be a good way to include the full path?

Comment: Try the way you have it first but Full path would be your full directory to images folder. exampe. `C:/www/mysite/images`

Comment: Setting chmod 777 is never a good idea. 755 is sufficient for folders